# Replace multiple values on row based on condition in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, matlab, pandas

I have a csv of about 1000 records. One columns in the report is called level and includes string data like level 1, level 2 and so on. There are about 30 levels. Levels represent revenue levels for companies. So, company level 1 means they do less then 1M in revenue. I can find a way to replace values one by one by doing something like:

```
df.loc[df['Level'] == 'Level 1', 'Level'] = 1000000
```

Is there a way for me to apply the same logic to all records? Maybe I can throw everything in a dictionary:

```
dict = {
       'Level 1': 1000000,
       'Level 2': 2000000, 
}
```

I want to do scatter plot of all companies by type and revenue level so maybe there is also a way to do this in matlab?

Comment: In Matlab, what are the inputs and outputs exactly? Have you already loaded the csv file into Matlab variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [**`pd.Series.map`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html)

Consider `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    Level=['Level {}'.format(i) for i in [1, 2, 3, 2, 1]],
    Other=range(5)
))

df

     Level  Other
0  Level 1      0
1  Level 2      1
2  Level 3      2
3  Level 2      3
4  Level 1      4
```

Assign your `dct`

```
dct = {'Level 1': 1000000,
       'Level 2': 2000000,
       'Level 3': 3000000}
```

And

```
df.assign(Level=df.Level.map(dct))

     Level  Other
0  1000000      0
1  2000000      1
2  3000000      2
3  2000000      3
4  1000000      4
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html):

```
df['Level'] = df['Level'].replace(dict)
```

Note: you shouldn't use `dict` as a variable name as it shadows the buildin `dict`.

Comment: `df.replace({'Level': dct})`  also

Comment: Thank you both. Will try it when I am back at the computer.